# Do native people pronounce "it is on the table" as "ɪt sɑːn ðə ˈteɪbl" or "ɪt zɑːn ðə ˈteɪbl"?

Tags: pronunciation, contractions, weak-forms

Sometimes, when I watch American films, I often hear people say "**ɪt zɑːn ðə ˈteɪbl**" (it is on the table).

I learned in textbook that "**it is**" can be contracted as "**it's**" and since "**t**" is voiceless so we have to pronounce "**it's**" as "**ɪts**" not "**ɪtz**".

But people, especially American ones often say "**ɪt zɑːn ðə ˈteɪbl**" (it is on the table).

Then I checked the dictionary

> **[is](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/is)**
>
> UK  strong /ɪz/ weak **/z/** **/s/** US  strong /ɪz/ weak /z/ /s/

---

So I guessed that there is no contraction in the sentence "**it is on the table**", people pronounce it as  "**ɪt zɑːn ðə ˈteɪbl**" and **/z/** is the weak form of "**is**".

**did I guess right?**

Comment: As a native speaker, I'd definitely interpret "ɪt zɑːn" as *it's on*, not *it is on*.

Comment: @MikeGraham, but "t" is voiceless & you broke the pronunciation rule

Comment: When you have a common phrase with a word that ends with a consonant followed by a word beginning with a vowel, it's common for them to run together. Is that what you're asking about?

Answer (score 3):

In American English we would pronounce "it is on" as /ɪɾɪzɑːn/ or /ɪdɪzɑːn/, and "it's on" as /ɪtsɑːn/ or /ɪdzɑːn/. /tz/ is not present in any dialect of American English, and if you think you're hearing it, you're almost certainly actually hearing /dz/, /ts/, or /t z/; in the latter case, the /t/ comes at the end of a word and /z/ at the beginning of another word. This is because consonant clusters must have uniform voicing in American English.